# python 2.7 simple proxy server

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, proxy, server

i want to make a simple proxy server in python
this is what it needs to do:
- get a url from the client
- fetch the content of that url
- manipulate every link in that site
- return the manipulated site to the user

the only thing i managed to do so far (using either urllib or requests) is a simple redirection of the required url
meaning i could not even return to the user the response object i hold

any ideas on how to do that?

the code i have so far:

```
import BaseHTTPServer
import requests
from urlparse import urlparse
import HTTPClient


PORT = 443


class Proxy(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_HEAD(self):
        query = urlparse(self.path).query
        query_components = dict(qc.split("=") for qc in query.split("?"))
        new_url = query_components['url']
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        self.send_response(301)
        #self.send_header('Location', new_url)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(r.content)
    def do_GET(self):
        query = urlparse(self.path).query
        query_components = dict(qc.split("=") for qc in query.split("?"))
        if query_components['url'].find('http://') != 0:
            self.send_error(400, "Bad Url - Http Required")
        else:
            self.do_HEAD()



try:
    httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('localhost', PORT), Proxy)
    print "Serving at port", PORT
    httpd.serve_forever()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    httpd.server_close()
    print "Closing Server"
```

i even tried somehow to return 'r' (the actual response object) but it didnt work

the line in comment is for a simple redirection without even holding the site's content

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

This should work on linux, hopefully it will give you a starting point.

```
import SocketServer
import SimpleHTTPServer
import urllib

PORT = 1234

class Proxy(SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        self.copyfile(urllib.urlopen(self.path), self.wfile)

httpd = SocketServer.ForkingTCPServer(('', PORT), Proxy)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```